# How does a smart satellite navigation system work?

Tags: gps, smartphone, satellite

How does a smart navigation system work where not only does it tell you the location ( within your route) where there is a traffic jam but also how long it will take for you to pass the jam.

Comment: Using lots of data and complicated logic.  This question is far too vague to answer.

Comment: I just listened to something on the radio and wanted to ask a question

Comment: Yes, but your question is far too vague.  A proper answer to this question would fill at least one book.

Comment: On the radio it says that mobile phones and gps devices send it data to a system.  How does that system then determines how long a car is going to be stuck in traffic? I think once it sends the data, the system compares it with other data it has received from the same location, the checks to see if a car has moved in a given time, if not, it know that there might be a traffic jam.

Comment: well i do not want you to write a book, just give a brief answer. Its not for university or anything just out of curiosity.

Comment: Your comment is asking a much more specific question; your supposition is probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

How long it takes:
This works by measuring the transit times ( via GPS) through each street segment, sending to a central server, either via GSM if the device has that built in, or when you connect the navigation device to your home computer, it connects with the server.
there it is categorized by day categories (weekday, saturday, sunday, local holiday, day before holiday etc.) and time (e.g evry 10 - 15 minutes). 

This build up a data base of transit times. you can buy that from TomTom and from Navteq  for some huge amount of dollar.
(today nearly all smarthphones sends traffic situation data to a central server, either to Apple, or to Google. In ios you have to disable that option if you dont want that)

traffic jams:
Works only with devices which have Internet connection (GSM):
very slow speed on road segements are reported to a central server, which builds up the current traffic situation.